# calculate the count and then sum of total count MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

My Query

```
$sql = 'SELECT status FROM tablename';
```

And the result

```
------------
status
------------
assigned
assigned
assigned
assigned
assigned
accepted
accepted
completed
completed
completed
completed
completed
```

Now i can find the total count of each status

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS cnt
FROM tname
GROUP BY b.statusName
HAVING (cnt >= 1)
```

This will give

---

```
status     cnt
--------------
accepted    2
assigned    5
completed   5
```

How do i sum only `completed` and `accepted` count?

Comment: Try it with a subselect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called conditional summing, when you place the condition within the sum() function:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status IN ('accepted','assigned'),cnt,0)) as sum_of_acc_asg
FROM    
    (SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS cnt
    FROM tname
    GROUP BY b.statusName
    HAVING (cnt > 1)) t
```

Or you can use where to filter the subquery first:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) as sum_of_acc_asg
FROM    
    (SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS cnt
    FROM tname
    WHERE status IN ('accepted','assigned')
    GROUP BY b.statusName
    HAVING (cnt > 1)) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, replace `group by` by  `where`

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS cnt
 FROM tname 
 WHERE b.statusName IN ('completed','accepted')
 HAVING (cnt > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  COUNT(status) AS cnt
 FROM tname 
 WHERE status='completed' or status='accepted'